# Python pandas equivalent to R groupby mutate

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

So in R when I have a data frame consisting of say 4 columns, call it `df` and I want to compute the ratio by sum product of a group, I can it in such a way:

```
// generate data
df = data.frame(a=c(1,1,0,1,0),b=c(1,0,0,1,0),c=c(10,5,1,5,10),d=c(3,1,2,1,2));
| a   b   c    d |
| 1   1   10   3 |
| 1   0   5    1 |
| 0   0   1    2 |
| 1   1   5    1 |
| 0   0   10   2 |
// compute sum product ratio
df = df%>% group_by(a,b) %>%
      mutate(
          ratio=c/sum(c*d)
      );
| a   b   c    d  ratio |
| 1   1   10   3  0.286 |
| 1   1   5    1  0.143 |
| 1   0   5    1  1     |
| 0   0   1    2  0.045 |
| 0   0   10   2  0.454 |
```

But in python I need to resort to loops.
I know there should be a more elegant way than raw loops in python, anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Another really powerful part of mutate is there is no need for scoping, you can simply write c/sum(c*d) and it knows it is referring to the data frame that came from the left. I find it unnecessary verbose and obfuscating in python a need to write lambda g: g.c/(g.c*g.d).sum()

Comment: @jedi I agree, but there is nothing you can do, when you have to use python...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to this [thread on pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9229) we can use the  `transform()` method to replicate the combination of `dplyr::groupby()` and `dplyr::mutate()`. For this example, it would look as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        a=(1 , 1, 0, 1, 0 ), 
        b=(1 , 0, 0, 1, 0 ),
        c=(10, 5, 1, 5, 10),
        d=(3 , 1, 2, 1, 2 ),
    )
).assign(
    prod_c_d = lambda x: x['c'] * x['d'], 
    ratio    = lambda x: x['c'] / (x.groupby(['a','b']).transform('sum')['prod_c_d'])
)
```

This example uses [pandas method chaining](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining). For more information on how to use method chaining to replicate `dplyr` workflows see this [blogpost](https://www.datisticsblog.com/2018/08/r2py_pandas/).

The method using `apply()` and `groupby()` does not work for me because it does not seem to be adaptable. For example, it does not work if we delete `g.c/` from the lambda expression.

```
df['ratio'] = df.groupby(['a','b'], group_keys=False)\
    .apply(lambda g: (g.c * g.d).sum() )
```

Comment: what about when we want to assign 2+ columns in the same call that each make use of `.groupby(['a','b'])`? Is there a "neater" way than repeating the groupby method for each column like so?

`df = df.assign(c_lag1 = lambda x: x['c'].groupby(['a','b']).shift(-1), c_lag2 = lambda x: x['c'].groupby(['a','b']).shift(-2))`

Comment: you could predefine the group object but it will break the method chain
`gr = df['c'].groupby(['a','b'])
df.assign(c_lag = gr.shift(-1), c_lag2 = gr.shift(-2))`

Comment: Could you explain further why do we need `lambda` within `assign`? I can't figure out what does `x` refers to. Original `DataFrame` or some subgroups?

Comment: a lambda expression is a method to write one-line one-keyword functions. When using it within the `assign` method `x` calls the original dataframe with all changes that have already been made upstream of the current method chain.
https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining.html

Comment: is this still the best way to do it?, is there something better coming for this in pandas 1.0?, …, this way is the better I've found around, but it seems not very efficient (transform('sum') over all columns, when u only need one).

Comment: i think you can adapt the first approach by adding a column of 1s: `df['ones'] = 1; df['sumofprod'] = df.groupby(['a','b'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.ones*(g.c * g.d).sum())`

Answer (score 39):

It can be done with similar syntax with `groupby()` and `apply()`:

```
df['ratio'] = df.groupby(['a','b'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.c/(g.c * g.d).sum())
```

[image]

Comment: What does the group_keys=False achieve?

Comment: By default, `groupby()` adds the group columns as extra index to the result which makes its index different from the original data frame and thus it can't be assigned the data frame easily. Avoid adding the group columns as keys makes the assignment possible as long as each row has a unique index.

Comment: well, this is far as practical as mutate. The big advantage of mutate is that you can create a new variable within a pipiline and keep chaining things, whereas this needs you to dedicate a specific line to assigning the new column. Isn't there an "inplace=True" method to create an additional column to a panda?

Answer (score 11):

It's pretty easy to translate your R code into python with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, c, tibble, sum, group_by, mutate
[2021-06-24 13:32:29][datar][WARNING] Builtin name "sum" has been overriden by datar.
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(a=c(1,1,0,1,0),b=c(1,0,0,1,0),c=c(10,5,1,5,10),d=c(3,1,2,1,2))
>>> df
        a       b       c       d
  <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64>
0       1       1      10       3
1       1       0       5       1
2       0       0       1       2
3       1       1       5       1
4       0       0      10       2
>>> df >> group_by(f.a, f.b) >> mutate(ratio=f.c/sum(f.c*f.d))
        a       b       c       d     ratio
  <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64> <float64>
0       1       1      10       3  0.285714
1       1       0       5       1  1.000000
2       0       0       1       2  0.045455
3       1       1       5       1  0.142857
4       0       0      10       2  0.454545

[Groups: a, b (n=3)]
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.

Comment: This package looks pretty promising! I'll have to check it out. I an R Junkie who dabbles in Python.