# Function in pandas dataframe that replicates dplyr group_by(multiple variables) function in R

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

Consider this case:

[Python pandas equvilant to R groupby mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923165/python-pandas-equvilant-to-r-groupby-mutate)

In `dplyr`:

```
df = df%>% group_by(a,b) %>%
```

means first the dataframe is grouped by column `a` then by `b`.

In my case I am trying to group my data first by `group_name` column, then by `user_name` , then by `type_of_work` . There are more than three columns (which is why I got confused) but I need data grouped according to these three headers in the same order. I already have an algorithm to work with columns after this stage. I only need an algorithm for creating a dataframe grouped according to these three columns.

It is important in my case that the sequence is preserved like the `dplyr` function.

Do we have anything similar in `pandas` data-frame?

Comment: Did you read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)?

Comment: Try df.groupby?

Comment: @EdChum I got stuck while using groupby and apply method because apparently groupby cannot be assigned to dataframe easily.

Answer (score 0):

Grouped = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])

Read more on "split-apply-combine" strategy in the pandas docs to see how pandas deals with these issues compared to R.

From your comment it seem you want assign the grouped frames. You can either use a groupbyobject through the API, eg grouped.mean(), or you can iterate through the groupby object. You will get name and group in each loop.